# How to show array elements in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I have the following HTML code. I have commented the part of code which i want to repeat again for displaying the elements of the array. And my array contains names like this:- `var name=['amit','mayank','jatin'];`. So i want to display 10 such blocks as my array contains 10 such names which are fetched from backend.

```html
<div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-table100">
            <div class="wrap-table100">
                    <div class="table">

                        <div class="row header">
                            <div class="cell">
                                Rank
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell">
                                Name
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell">
                                Quiz Name
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell">
                                Scores
                            </div>
                        </div>
//repeat below code
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="cell" data-title="Full Name">
                                1
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell" data-title="Age">
                                Amit Singh
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell" data-title="Job Title">
                                Python Quiz
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell" data-title="Location">
                                100
                            </div>
                        </div>
//till here
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a table from array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505217/generate-a-table-from-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of way , this is one of them.

In this example we have a `querySelector` which gets the element with class name `data` so the HTML code can be inserted in this place.

The `map()` method is used to call the provided function once for each element in an array, in order, so the table with all the data of the array can be created.

I hope be useful for you.

```js
const dataElement = document.querySelector('.data');

const data = [
  {fullName: 'Nathan', age: 21, jobTitle: 'Programmer', location: 'IRAN'},
  {fullName: 'Ali', age: 21, jobTitle: 'Programmer', location: 'UK'},
  {fullName: 'Ariana', age: 21, jobTitle: 'Programmer', location: 'US'},
];

data.map(item => {
  dataElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
      <div class="cell" data-title="Full Name">
          ${item.fullName}
      </div>
      <div class="cell" data-title="Age">
          ${item.age}
      </div>
      <div class="cell" data-title="Job Title">
          ${item.jobTitle}
      </div>
      <div class="cell" data-title="Location">
          ${item.location}
      </div>
`)
})
```

```html
<div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-table100">
            <div class="wrap-table100">
                    <div class="table">

                        <div class="row header">
                            <div class="cell">
                                Rank
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell">
                                Name
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell">
                                Quiz Name
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell">
                                Scores
                            </div>
                        </div>
//repeat below code
                        <div class="row data">
                        </div>
//till here
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, but needed some changes like replace afterbegin with beforeend and in query selector change .data with .table. As there was no padding among the elements.

Comment: You should be using `forEach()` here since you're not doing anything with the array returned from `map()` see: [JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map)

Answer (score 1):

Convert that element to string, loop through the given array, insert using `insertAdjacentHTML`.

```
const names = ['amit', 'mayank', 'jatin'];

const tableBody = names
  .map((name) => `
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell" data-title="Full Name">1</div>
      <div class="cell" data-title="Age">${name}</div>
      <div class="cell" data-title="Job Title">Python Quiz</div>
      <div class="cell" data-title="Location">100</div>
    </div>`).join('');

const rowHeader = document.querySelector('.table > .header');

rowHeader.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', tableBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of objects, iterate through it to create a string with HTML which you will append into your HTML, and then append it.

```
const tableEl = document.querySelector('.table');
let htmlToAppend = "";
let data = [
    {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age: 20,
        job: 'Cashier',
        location: 'London'
    },
    {
        name: 'Jane Doe',
        age: 30,
        job: 'Taxi driver',
        location: 'New York'
    },
    {
        name: 'Bill Gates',
        age: 65,
        job: 'Entertainer',
        location: 'Moldovia'
    },
    {
        name: 'Donald Darko',
        age: 19,
        job: 'Student',
        location: 'Middlesex'
    },
    ];

data.forEach(entry => {
       htmlToAppend += `<div class="row">
                            <div class="cell" data-title="Full Name">
                                ${entry.name}
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell" data-title="Age">
                                ${entry.age}
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell" data-title="Job Title">
                                ${entry.job}
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell" data-title="Location">
                                ${entry.location}
                            </div>
                        </div>`
})

tableEl.innerHTML = htmlToAppend;
```